# How To print get something on response in postman if the server successfully processed the request but it is not returning any content?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, postman, loopback4

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj7Y9.png)

Here in this screenshot you can see it returned the OTP successfully but how to get the content in response in loopback4?
Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: The screenshot you added is the body you provided to send to the server . The screen shot doesn't show anything other than 204 for server side . Could you add the details of what url you are trying

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to identify the expected output in your question.

### Print somthing out in postman

Cause it is using javascript you can simply use the `console.log()`

**Print response**

```
console.log(pm.response)
```

Sample output: `{id: "7817f7b6-037d-45ef-a033-05001cca84b6", status: "OK", code: 200…}`

**Print json of response**

```
console.log(pm.response.json())
```

Sample output: `{authToken: "RhHutA0vICpOa3fIQpiRlBUhBVUx", token_type: "bearer", expires_in: "3600"…}`